# Ошибка при добавлении в автозагрузку через реестр на python: PermissionError: Отказано в доступе

Tags: python, python-3.x, autoload

Добавляю скрипт на python в автозагрузку через реестр:

```
file_path = __file__

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'test', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, file_path)
key.Close()
```

При выполнении  получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File ...
        winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'test', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, file_path)
    PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе
```

Пробовала запускать IDE и сам скрипт от имени администратора, не помогло.

Comment: Напишите `access=winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE`, т.к. у `winreg.OpenKey()` 4 аргумента и `access` как раз четвёртый, а у вас - третий.

Comment: @GrAnd спасибо, это помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправленный код:

```
file_path = __file__

key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run',
access=winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)

winreg.SetValueEx(key, 'test', 0, winreg.REG_SZ, file_path)
key.Close()
```